# Convert a Piecewise Polynomial Function into a Single Expression/Model

Tags: java, math, numerical-methods, polynomial-math, numerical-analysis

## Briefing

Suppose we had a continuous piecewise polynomial, how can we express it with a single equation or formula, through any programming language (preferably Java)?

In pure mathematics, I've found that it's possible to express the function in terms of an integral or a Heaviside step function. But the answer I couldn't find is **how to do the representation in programming**, if possible.

## More...

It's possible to pass x to, say, a [PolynomialSplineFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialSplineFunction.html#value(org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.differentiation.DerivativeStructure)) and get its y value.
[image: source: Wikipedia]

But what the function really does here is binary search an array of polynomials stored in the object, substitute in the right polynomial and return the value.

```
public double value(double v) {
        if (v < knots[0] || v > knots[n]) {
            throw new OutOfRangeException(v, knots[0], knots[n]);
        }
        int i = Arrays.binarySearch(knots, v);
        if (i < 0) {
            i = -i - 2;
        }
        // This will handle the case where v is the last knot value
        // There are only n-1 polynomials, so if v is the last knot
        // then we will use the last polynomial to calculate the value.
        if ( i >= polynomials.length ) {
            i--;
        }
    return polynomials[i].value(v - knots[i]);
}
```

What I'm looking for is an object that **would not** store arrays of values/polynomials and match to them later, **but** rather calculate such value in pretty much the same way of a regular mathematical formula (e.g **ax³ + bx² + cx + d**). That would be in code like this:

```
public double value(double x) {
            // the function will do more complex computation here (e.g. integration)
            return a*Math.pow(x, 3) + b*Math.pow(x, 2) + c*x + d;
}
```

Comment: @ArthurB. The point is printing out the "formula" to a documentation.

Comment: Then a typical way to write such formulas is with a big left brace, distinguishing one case on each line. Or you could define the set of intervals with indices, [a_i,b_i) and define for each i the polynomial P_i

Comment: @ArthurB. So it's impossible to write it as one formula, right?

Comment: It depends what you mean by a formula. If you are allowed to include indicator functions [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) in the formula, then if your spline is the value of poly p1 if x is in interval I1, of p2 if x is in the interval I2 then you can write spline = Ind_I1 * p1 + Ind_I2 * p2 + ...